# Still connect 22 ssh port when using gpinitsystem command of Greenplum withing different ssh port of CentOS7

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssh, greenplum

I want to install Greenplum in CentOS7.9 which is changed default ssh port to 10022. I changed 'gpssh-exkeys' script to add '-p 10022' for all of ssh command and add '-P 10022' for all of scp command. And run it is ok.
Then I changed '/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/python/gppylib/commands/base.py' script to add '-p 10022' in a ssh command line.

```
        # Escape " for remote execution otherwise it interferes with ssh
        cmd.cmdStr = cmd.cmdStr.replace('"', '\\"')
        cmd.cmdStr = "ssh -p 10022 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 " \
                     "{targethost} \"{gphome} {cmdstr}\"".format(targethost=self.targetHost,
                                                                 gphome=". %s/greenplum_path.sh;" % self.gphome,
                                                                 cmdstr=cmd.cmdStr)
```

But I got the error that present still try to connent port 22 when run 'gpinitsystem'.

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ gpinitsystem -c /home/gpadmin/gpinitsystem_config --locale=zh_CN -h /home/gpadmin/seg_hosts
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, please wait...
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Reading Greenplum configuration file /home/gpadmin/gpinitsystem_config
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No DATABASE_NAME set, will exit following template1 updates
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-MASTER_MAX_CONNECT not set, will set to default value 250
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, Completed
20220303:21:55:40:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, please wait...
.ssh: connect to host sdw1 port 22: Connection refused
.ssh: connect to host sdw2 port 22: Connection refused

20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Configuring build for multi-home array
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 630: ((: REMAINDER=2 % 0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 631: ((: MULTIPLE=2 / 0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 632: [: -ne: unary operator expected
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 632: [: -eq: unary operator expected
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 640: [: -gt: unary operator expected
20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, Completed
20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building primary segment instance array, please wait...

20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building group mirror array type , please wait...

20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking Master host
20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking new segment hosts, please wait...
ssh: connect to host sdw1 port 22: Connection refused
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 704: [: -eq: unary operator expected
ssh: connect to host mdw port 22: Connection refused
/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.19.3/bin/gpinitsystem: line 732: [: -lt: unary operator expected
ssh: connect to host mdw port 22: Connection refused
20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Postgres version does not match. [postgres (Greenplum Database) 6.19.3 build commit:33e10eef63ae25aeb33afbefdda46b6367353800 Open Source != ]
20220303:21:55:41:005293 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-Postgres version does not match Script Exiting!
```

And I didn't find official documents, https://docs.greenplum.org/, for guiding how to install withing the different ssh port.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do not modify delivered utilities.  Recommend leveraging ~gpadmin/.ssh/config specifying Port for your hosts.  All Greenplum utilities should honor settings in that file.

Example ~gpadmin/.ssh/config where all hosts are known as sdw1-pri, sdw2-pri and so on:

```
Host sdw*-pri
    Port 10022
```

Comment: It is positive solution. And don't need modify Greenplum utilities. Thank you very much! @Greg Spiegelberg

Comment: chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* permissions also needed

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the 10022 port in /etc/sshd_config and try again.

Comment: It was already modified for OS's ssh port. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

gpinitsystem internally calling REMOTE_EXECUTE_AND_GET_OUTPUT function which is part of <install_dir>/bin/lib/gp_bash_functions.sh file.

Currently gp_bash_functions.sh has below entries.

```
SSH=`findCmdInPath ssh`
if [ x"$TRUSTED_SHELL" = x"" ]; then TRUSTED_SHELL="$SSH"; fi
```

I think you may need to change the if condition like below

```
if [ x"$TRUSTED_SHELL" = x"" ]; then TRUSTED_SHELL="$SSH -p 10022"; fi
```

Comment: Thank you. And I think add configuration file, ~gpadmin/.ssh/config, is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Greg Spiegelberg. Show my ~gpadmin/.ssh/config:

```
Host    mdw
        HostName        mdw
        Port    10022

Host    smdw
        HostName        smdw
        Port    10022

Host    sdw1
        HostName        sdw1
        Port    10022

Host    sdw2
        HostName        sdw2
        Port    10022
```

Priority of ssh config: specified parameter for command > .ssh/config > /etc/ssh/ssh_config